# Evaluate this without a calculator

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Evaluate $$1^{2017}+2^{2017}+...+1000^{2017}(\text{mod}\; 2016)$$
These large exponents prevent me from finding any quick method to find the mod.

Comment: most likely a solution exists here already.

Comment: No, 2^2017 is 128 mod 2016 I believe

Comment: i think you have interchanged the 2016 and 2017....could you check for once?

Comment: No 2017 is the power and 2016 is the mod

Answer (score 5):

$2016 = 2^5 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7$, so do it mod $2^5$, $3^2$ and $7$ and use Chinese Remainder Theorem.

For $2^5 = 32$, note that $\phi(2^5) = 16$, and $2017 \equiv 1 \mod 16$ so
$a^{2017} \equiv a \mod 2^5$ if $a$ is odd, while $a^{2017} \equiv 0 \mod 2^5$ if $a$ is even.  Thus
$1^{2017} + 2^{2017} + \ldots 1000^{2017} \equiv 1 + 3 + \ldots + 999 = 250000 \equiv 16 \mod 2^5$.

I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: "It" meaning...?

Comment: Find the sum mod $2^5$ (which I did for you), the sum mod $3^2$ and the sum mod $7$.